# Data fetched from API is not showing in Angular

Tags: angular, api

I am fetching data from SQL server through a back-end API in asp.net, and everything is going well I am fetching the data as well but it's not showing on the screen only in the console here is a picture to understand what I am trying to achieve

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwsXb.png)

Here is my .service:

```
GetCategories(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.BaseUrl);
    // return this.afs.collection<any>('Categories').valueChanges();
  }
```

and here is my .ts :

```
GetCategories() {
    this.api.GetCategories().subscribe({
      next: (Categ) => {
        this.categories = Categ;
        console.log(this.categories);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    });
  }
```

and my .HTML :

```
<mat-form-field fxLayoutAlign="center center" (click)="GetCategories()">
      <mat-label> Filter by Categories</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="FilterCateg($event)">
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let Categ of categories"
          [value]="Categ.categories"
          class="DropDown-color"
        >
          {{ Categ.categories }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

From my experience it should be displaying but I don't know what I am doing wrong, thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `Categ.categories` is suspicious, since `Categ` will hold just one category. create a model interface, then you can get rid of the `any`s and have intellisense on your objects

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `{{ Categ.categories }}`, according to the data shown in your screenshot, you're dealing with a single category at this point. Thus it should be `{{ Categ.categoryName }}` instead.

And likewise, `[value]="Categ.categories"` should be `[value]="Categ.categoryID"`.

Comment: thank you, i haven't noticed that I was passing two values on my drop-down list , silly me

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the html template, in there you use `Categ.categories` but probably categories no is a key in your Categ object.

You can see on your `console.log(this.categories)` the objects elements and decide which you want use to renderize in your template or binding in somewhere else.